# Python Import Order

Tags: python, python-2.7

The documentation for Python 2.7.10 states that

> When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches for a file named spam.py in a list of directories given by the variable sys.path

However this happens when I have a file `site.py` in my CWD:

```
import site
print(site.__file__)
>>> site.py
```

So obviously `site` was not identified as a builtin-module first, but imported from the CWD instead. Any ideas as to what might be wrong there?

Comment: `site` is _not_ a builtin module

Comment: Actually it is: https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html
However, my python behaves as described in the docs

Comment: Where in that doc do you see that it should be a builtin? A builtin module (like for example `sys`) does not have a `.py` file, `site` does come from `site.py`.

Comment: I have another machine running Python 2.7.3 however, and there Python behaves as described. I.e. it doesn't matter whether I have a `site.py` in the CWD or not, it's always imported from `'/usr/lib/python2.7/site.pyc'`

Comment: do you have `__init__.py` file in your CWD?

Comment: @Nhor No there is no `__init__.py`

Comment: @mata you're right, it's not "built in" but a lib which comes with py…

Comment: Alright, `site` is not a builtin. So the behavior described in my question is the expected behavior. Would anyone have a clue as to what might be the cause for my other machine behaving differently then?

Comment: @karlson - is your `PYTHONPATH` set? `site` seems to be imported before the CWD is added to `sys.path`, but the `PYTHONPATH` env variable is added earlier if set.

Comment: @mata Very nice catch, that solved it! `PYTHONPATH` is set on both machines. On the former machine it ended with `:`, however, on the latter it does not. After unsetting the variable `site` is not imported from the CWD anymore. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure `site` is built-in module?

```
import sys
sys.builtin_module_names
```

should give you built-in modules.